# Self Trigger RapidMiner Process

Tags: rapidminer

I have created a process in Rapid Miner Studio for retraining.
The first operator that I use  in this Process is "Process Documents from File" where I fill up the value for "Text Directories" i.e. the file locations which it picks up to get retrained.

My requirement is that, whenever there is addition of files in that location, the process should get triggered by itself to get retrained on the new files.

Is this capability present in Rapid Miner?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a scheduled job in RapidMiner Server. This would be controlled with cron like parameters and could initiate any process. This may not be what you want however since there would be a delay between the file being available and it being processed and I suppose there is the possibility that files being written could be partially read.

Comment: I dont want the process to get triggered through a scheduler. Instead, it should self trigger itself whenever there is an addition of files in the input directory from which it is reading.

Comment: I just came across triggers in Rapid Miner server. Will that help ?

Comment: They look like they might do what you want.